# Remove listener from value notifier using dart in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have an integer value that is provided by listening to a value notifier, I want to remove the listener after the integer reaches a certain value.

I have tried to use the 'listener.removelisteners' but I couldn't achieve what I wanted

```
void checktrials() {
    trialsonline.addListener((){
        print('started listener');
        if(trialsonline.value==1){
            print('out of trials');
            trialsonline.value=0;
            //here i want to remove the listener 
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
var f;
f = () {
   print('started listener');
   if (trialsonline.value == 1) {
     print('out of trials');
     trialsonline.value = 0;
     trialsonline.removeListener(f);
   }
};
```

and add like this:

```
trialsonline.addListener(f);
```

Comment: Hi what if we want to pass some parameters to our listener functions? Then how can we remove them? My listener is using variables from another scope